# weighted counting in python

Tags: python, count

I want to count the instances of `X` in a list, similar to

[How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

but taking into account a weight for each instance.

For example,

```
L = [(a,4), (a,1), (b,1), (b,1)]
```

the function `weighted_count()` should return something like

```
[(a,5), (b,2)]
```

Edited to add: my a, b will be integers.

Comment: How have tried to solve this so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you a dictionary of all the letters in the array and their corresponding counts

```
counts = {}
for value in L:
    if value[0] in counts:
        counts[value[0]] += value[1]
    else:
        counts[value[0]] = value[1]
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for a very specific value. You can filter the list for that value, then map the list to the weights and find the sum of them.

```
def countOf(x,L):
    filteredL = list(filter(lambda value: value[0] == x,L))
    return sum(list(map(lambda value: value[1], filteredL)))
```

Answer (score 7):

you can still use counter:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for k,v in L:
    c.update({k:v})
print c
```

Comment: This does not seem to remember the ordering. For example, doing this for 
 [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (5, 1), (2, 2)]  output  Counter({1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 1, 5: 1})

Comment: Thanks! Note also that c.update({k:1.5}) also seems to work (i.e. non-integral values are also allowed).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> L = [ ('a',4), ('a',1), ('b',1), ('b',1) ]
>>> [(k, sum(amt for _,amt in v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(L), key=lambda tup: tup[0])]
[('a', 5), ('b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`defaultdict` will do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [('a',4), ('a',1), ('b',1), ('b',1)]
res = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in L:
    res[k] += v
print(list(res.items()))
```

prints:

```
[('b', 2), ('a', 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Group items with the occurrence of first element of each tuple using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.groupby) from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L = [('a',4), ('a',1), ('b',1), ('b',1)]
>>> L_new = []
>>> for k,v in groupby(L,key=itemgetter(0)):
    L_new.append((k,sum(map(itemgetter(1), v))))

>>> L_new
[('a', 5), ('b', 2)]
>>> L_new = [(k,sum(map(itemgetter(1), v))) for k,v in groupby(L, key=itemgetter(0))] #for those fun of list comprehension and one liner expression
>>> L_new
[('a', 5), ('b', 2)]
```

Tested in both Python2 & Python3

Answer (score 0):

Use the dictionaries `get` method.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for item in L:
...     d[item[0]] = d.get(item[0], 0) + item[1]
... 
>>> d
{'a': 5, 'b': 2}
```